# How to compute the spatial forces acting on a body/ manipulator end-effector?

Tags: drake

I want to obtain the spatial forces acting on a body from `MultibodyPlant` without simulating the plant. In particular, I have a 7 DoF manipulator and wish to obtain the spatial forces acting on its last link (operational space form of the inverse dynamics).

I could obtain these using the pseudo-inverse of the spatial Jacobian (`F = J^{-T} @ tau`), where generalized forces `tau` are computed using `CalcInverseDynamics`. However, this is rather inefficient, especially as I want to differentiate through them with respect to plant parameters (system ID).

There is also [get_reaction_forces_output_port](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#a5b03afbfe072f83e3681cf9798121eb2). However, this would require simulating the plant.

There exists an internal C++ overload of `CalcInverseDynamics` that is called by the public version of `CalcInverseDynamics` and computes the spatial forces (see [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/tree/multibody_tree.cc#L1502)).
Moreover, there is an even closer function to what I want, called [CalcJointReactionForces](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1benchmarks_1_1kuka__iiwa__robot_1_1_drake_kuka_i_iwa_robot.html#a8fcedd77201a6ff4ee603c107277a650) that computes the spatial forces for each joint of the iiwa manipulator. However, it lives in `benchmarks` and is not general enough to be useful in wider contexts (e.g. no way to initialize the context).

How can I achieve this with a public API method?

Comment: Why do you say that "get_reaction_forces_output_port" would require simulating the plant?  Given a plant and a context, you can call `plant.get_reaction_forces_output_port().Eval(context)` to evaluate the method.

Comment: Ups. That is fair. I'm not used to using ports this way and completely missed that. This solves my issue then. thanks!

Comment: Thinking about this more, I don't believe the reaction forces are what I want. I find the documentation quite confusing here but I believe that the correct spatial forces should require accelerations in their computation. So, the spatial inverse dynamics direction seems more appropriate. Is this correct, or am I confusing things here?